# Handling contact form submissions Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've inherited a website built using Codeigniter (v2.1.4). The client has asked for a change, and I'm not sure of the best way to achieve it.

I have the following method in the Main controller that powers a new vans page.

```
public function new_vans($slug = null){
    $this->load->view('inc/header_view');
    if($slug === NULL){
        //If no slug is provided, show all new vans
        $this->load->view('new_vans_view');
    }else{
        //If there is a slug, just show the selected van, or redirect if nothing returned
        $data['new_van'] = $this->Database->getSingle('new_vans', array('slug' => $slug));
        if(!empty($data['new_van'])){
            $this->load->view('new_van_details_view',$data);
        }else{
            redirect('/new-vans');
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('inc/footer_view');
}
```

The client has asked for a contact form to be added to a couple of pages including this one, and my question is, should I create a new method that just handles the contact form submissions? If so, how would I handle sending validation errors back to the page? The contact forms will all have the same fields, so I would guess creating a new method is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Partial Views(forms)

Partial views are good for forms, they can be re-used
like your client has requested.

---

### Returning views as data

> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior
> of the function so that it returns data as a
> string rather than sending it to your browser.
> This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way.
> If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data.
> The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser.
> Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);
```

---

### Master layouts

To create a Master layout so you can wrap your views
create a new file inside your views directory

**views/master/layout.php**

```
<body>
    <?php $this->load->view($view); ?>
</body>
```

---

### Controller

```
class someController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->template = 'master/layout';
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->load->view($this->template, array(
            'view'  =>  'somecontrollerview',
            'contact_form'  =>  $this->load->view('partials/forms/contact', array(), true)
        ));
    }
}
```

---

### somecontrollerview

Echo out the contact form(string)

```
<?php echo $contact_form; ?>
```

### Contact Controller

Create a new Controller to handle your form validation

Answer (score 0):

The client has asked for a contact form to be added to a couple of pages including this one, and my question is, should I create a new method that just handles the contact form submissions?

> create a new controller and new methods

If so, how would I handle sending validation errors back to the page?

> look through the codeigniter documentation for form validation. basically if they have an error you are going to show them a view with the form again. it does not matter which page they came "from".

The contact forms will all have the same fields, so I would guess creating a new method is the way to go?

> you need to validate the form fields, hopefully capture the contact info to a database, send  an email confirmation to the customer, and send an email to the sales person unless its being done directly from the database, and then show a view with a thank you.
>
> each one of those steps is a separate method.
>
> optionally you can show the email address on the thank you page saying 'we have sent you a copy to the email address: something@gmail.com -- that way if the customer messed up the email address they can go back and correct it.